# How to Convert Adjacency Matrix to Adjacency List in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list, converters

I am trying to implement a method to convert an adjacency matrix into an adjacency list. My implementation does not correctly convert from a matrix into a list. 
This was my first attempt at it,

```js
//Adjacency Matrix to Adjc list

function convertToAdjList(adjMatrix) {
  var adjList = new Array(adjMatrix.length - 1);

  for (var i = 0; i < adjMatrix.length; i++) {
    if (adjMatrix[i] == 1) {
      //I think i have to do something here.
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < adjMatrix.length - 1; j++) {
      if (adjMatrix[i][j] == 1) {
        adjList[i] = i;//not sure if this is quite right.
      }
    }
  }
  return adjList;
}
var testMatrix = [
  [0, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 0, 0]
];
console.log(convertToAdjList(testMatrix)); //[[1,2,3],[0],[0],[0];
```

The output is just one of the 4 arrays i expected the code to output, plus a zero at index 0. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix that?

Comment: Why did you expect more than one array?  Where would they come from?

Comment: why do you have `[0, 4, 5],` instead of `[0]`?

Comment: shoot. Sorry. I condensed a larger matrix and list for testing purposes, and that is a typo. And i would expect a multi dimensional array, a list of lists of adjacency. Right? because an adjacency list would list  what is adjacent to it, not just how many times something is adjacent to it, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the indices or `-1` as unwanted value and then filter this value.

```js
function convertToAdjList(adjMatrix) {
    return adjMatrix.map(a => a.map((v, i) => v ? i : -1).filter(v => v !== -1))
}

var testMatrix = [ [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]];

console.log(convertToAdjList(testMatrix)); // [[1, 2, 3], [0], [0], [0]]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I was not aware JavaScript had that as a built in function. That is actually really cool. Thank you very much. I will look into the documentation of .map and .filter to better understand this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would this be an asymptotic complexity of O(n^2) because .filter is nested into .map?

Answer (score 1):

The other way without using 'map' is to write it like below, which might not be that good, but still will do the job.

```js
function convertToAdjList(adjMatrix) {
  var adjList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < adjMatrix.length; i++) {
    var array=[];
    for (var j = 0; j < adjMatrix.length; j++) {
      if (adjMatrix[i][j] == 1) {
        array.push(j);
      }
    }
    adjList[i]=array;

  }
   return adjList;
}
```

It can be mentioned that time complexity would be like O(V^2). However, I guess if we want to convert adjacency list to adjacency matrix, the time complexity will be like O(V*E).